# Model observer is not firing while updating

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I have an issue while trying to use an observer that it doesn't fire the observer only in the updated case. it works fine in other cases !.

I had some research about it and I found some solutions, such as calling the update method directly from the model, not in a repository, but unfortunately, it didn't work for me.
the solution I found: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/11777#issuecomment-170388067

UserObserver

```php
class UserObserver
{
    /**
     * Handle the user "created" event.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\User  $user
     * @return void
     */
    public function created(User $user)
    {
        dd($user);
    }

    /**
     * Handle the user "updated" event.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\User  $user
     * @return void
     */
    public function updated(User $user)
    {
        dd($user);
    }

    /**
     * Handle the user "deleted" event.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\User  $user
     * @return void
     */
    public function deleted(User $user)
    {
        dd($user);
    }
}
```

and here's my `AppServiceProvider`:

```php
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        User::observe(UserObserver::class);
    }
}
```

I called the `update` method in my controller like this:

```php
// First try
$user = User::findOrFail($id);
$user->update($data);
// Second try
User::findOrFail($id)->update($data);
```

this an example of my `$data` array:

```php
array [
  "nationality_id" => "1"
  "birth_date" => "2013-05-26"
  "gender" => "1"
  "job_title" => "Pariatur Sit provideeee"
  "salary" => "5100"
]
```

Answer (score 5):

Laravel checks if the model has actually been changed before firing updates, so make sure you change the model before saving or updating it.

Additionally, updating events are only fired when you update your model directly.

That means this will fire an event:

```
$user = User::findOrFail($id);
$user->update($data);
```

While something like this will not

```
User::where('id', $id)->update($data);
```

This is done by design, since using an update query could update millions of rows at once, making it unrealistic to fire events for all of them.

Comment: I already tryed this solution but it didn't work for me, I found the same solution in the issue link that I mentioned in my question.

Comment: @MuhammedElFeqy You need to show your actual code. Theoretically, your theoretical code works. What data are you passing into $data?

Comment: sorry that I forgot to figure it out, I updated my question now with an example of the data array

Comment: @MuhammedElFeqy and have you set the $fillable in the model?

Comment: yes, I tried both $guarded and $fillable,

Comment: I just realized somthing now, that if i use save() method instead of update it works, but it need to pass every single property, and it fires also while using mutators

Comment: @MuhammedElFeqy what dd you set for `fillable` as you don't use `guarded` and `fillable` together